# can macromedia flash 8 support m4a sound file

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-8

can anyone know macromedia flash 8 support m4a sound file or not. 
If it possible then how to implement on press the button and again stop sound.

Answer (score 0):

You could have:

```
var netconn:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
netconn.connect(null);

var stream_audio = new NetStream(netconn);

pause_btn.onPress = function() {
   stream_audio.pause();
}

play_btn.onPress = function() {
   stream_audio.play("audio.m4a");
}
```

Put this code in the first frame of your timeline, then create two buttons (movieclips) and name them "play_btn" and "pause_btn".